Define only one parameter using Marshmallow
I am using marshmallow serialization like this:
class BiblioMetadataSchema():
  """Schema for the biblio metadata."""
  rec_biblio = fields.Dict()

Data are comming from Elasticsearch and I need to define in current Json to be parameter category always array.
But I don't want to define all parameters inside rec_biblio because I never know what parameters there will be exactly.
So I need to say marshmallow that rec_biblio = fields.Dict() but rec_biblio["activity"]["category"] = fields.List()
Current Json
"rec_biblio": {
    "_id": "952822",
    "_legislation": "456/2012",
    "_lib_id": "1",
    "_updated": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "_version": "21007"
    "activity": {
      "id": "74154",
      "category" : ["AFS", "DUT"]
    }

Thanks everyone for your help!
I am not so much skilled SO...

You could create additional schemas and nest them in the appropriate attributes. Since you don't know which attributes will be present, you can configure the schemas to include unknown attributes.
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, INCLUDE


class ActivitySchema(Schema):
    category = fields.List(fields.Raw())

    class Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE


class RecBiblioSchema(Schema):
    activity = fields.Nested(ActivitySchema)

    class Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE


class BiblioMetadataSchema(Schema):
    """Schema for the biblio metadata."""
    rec_biblio = fields.Nested(RecBiblioSchema)

